# Is it possible "conditionally format" an entire row? Visually group similar rows?

Tags: google-sheets

With Google Sheets is it possible to color rows by a given column.... for example to alternate colors based on key in this spreadsheet:

| Key | Blah | Blah | Blah |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1233 | Blah | Blah | Blah |
| 1233 | Blah | Blah | Blah |
| 1223 | Blah | Blah | Blah |
| 1232 | Blah | Blah | Blah |
| 1232 | Blah | Blah | Blah |

So the colors would highlight 1233 and 1232 as distinct groups of rows.

The features "Alternating colors" and "Conditional formatting" are close but not quite this.

If this requires an attached script, is there a way to make it perform well, rather than have to reprocess the entire sheet each time there is an  edit?